# unpack / pack .apk with 7zip cause error during installation

Tags: android, apk, android-assets

I have a simple in-app browser that displays html files from /assets in a fullscreen WebView.

The idea is that customer can change those scripts himself without need of recompiling the APK.

I read few articles but when I tried to simply:

1. Rename .apk to .zip
2. Extract .zip
3. Zip the folder to .zip
4. Rename to .apk

When I transfer the .apk to my phone it reads "Error during analysis of the package" (Not exact error - translation from czech).

The ultimate goal is to change the files in assets folder (edit, add, delete).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Reaction to MichaelCMS

I tried:

1. Rename apk.apk to apk.zip
2. Extract .zip
3. Remove META-INF dir
4. Zip the folder to apk2.zip
5. Rename to apk2.apk

then I followed: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

```
jarsigner.exe -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore release-key.keystore app2.apk alias

zipalign.exe 4 app2.apk app-aligned.apk
```

The problem persists. Same error as before

Answer (score 1):

Apks need to be zip alligned, and also signed.

You can browse through an apk, but when repackaging him you need to remove the meta-inf , copress, zip align and sign (which will re-add the meta-inf folder).

Link to the documentation :

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not sufficient to produce a file with the correct extension using 7zip, you must ensure that you tell 7zip to use the standard zip compression using the `-tzip` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the trick is not to rename the app... Just go to 7zip, press Ctrl+o and open the apk!

If the problem persists, install the app on a phone and use apk extractor to create a new apk.